# How do I offset the navbar anchors so that the content is not hidden by the navbar itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, anchor

I'm making a code with HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I just couldn't figure out how to align the anchor links to the actual page. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

If you see the code below, you will notice that when I click on an anchor link, it will take you to the correct place, however part of the content will be hidden by the navbar itself, and I can't figure out how to add some kind of offset to it.

What I did to "solve" this problem was to just add padding to each section of the page, which makes it look decent, however you can still clearly see that the sections are divided before that point, which makes it look ugly.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
            <!-- I THINK IT'S ALREADY IN THE CSS FILE-->
        <!-- Collapsibles -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old Standard TT' rel='old-standard-font'>
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Responsive navbar                -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-darker fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Title</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#bg-bio">Biografía</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#bg-musica">Música</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#bg-media">Galería</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#bg-contacto">Redes Sociales</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Masthead-->
        <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column h-100">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-end">
                        <h1 class="text-white font-beba">Title</h1>
                        <hr class="divider-light" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-baseline">
                        <h2 class="text-white mb-5">Guitarrista - Cantante - Compositor</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- bio Section-->
        <section class="page-section text-dark mb-0" id="bg-bio">
            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-end">
                        <hr>
                        <h1 class="font-beba">Biografia</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <h2> Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="bg-bio">
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Musica Section-->
        <section class="page-section text-dark mb-0" id="bg-musica">
                <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-end">
                            <hr>
                            <h1 class="font-beba">Musica</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <ul class="list-group" id="myUL">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1"><h3>Cancion 1</h3></button>
                                        <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Bandcamp</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Spotify</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">YouTube</a></h5>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><h3>Cancion 2</h3></button>
                                        <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Bandcamp</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Spotify</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">YouTube</a></h5>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3"><h3>Cancion 3</h3></button>
                                        <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Bandcamp</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Spotify</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">YouTube</a></h5>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4"><h3>Cancion 4</h3></button>
                                        <div id="demo4" class="collapse">
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Bandcamp</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Spotify</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">YouTube</a></h5>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5"><h3>Cancion 5</h3></button>
                                        <div id="demo5" class="collapse">
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <br>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <h4>Letra de cancion</h4>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Bandcamp</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">Spotify</a></h5>
                                            <h5><a class="link-primary nounderline" href="">YouTube</a></h5>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- Media Section-->
        <section class="page-section bg-dark text-light mb-0" id="bg-media">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-end">
                            <hr>
                            <h1 class="font-beba">Galeria</h1>
                            <hr>
                            Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- Contact Section-->
        <section class="page-section text-dark mb-0 text-center" id="bg-contacto">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <hr>
                            <h1 class="font-beba">Sigueme en mis Redes Sociales</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <br>
                            <div class="footer-social-icons">
                                    <ul class="social-icons">
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- Copyright Section-->
        <div class="copyright py-4 text-center bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="container"><small>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</small></div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->
        <!-- * *                               SB Forms JS                               * *-->
        <!-- * * Activate your form at https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms * *-->
        <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->
        <script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Bare v5.0.2 (https://startbootstrap.com/template/bare)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-bare/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
// This file is intentionally blank
// Use this file to add JavaScript to your project
/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Freelancer v7.0.3 (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
//
// Scripts
//

function gotoHash('#mainNav') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $target = $('#mainNav'),
          scrollOffset = 100,
          y = $target.offset().top - scrollOffset;
  
      if ($target.length) {
        window.scrollTo(0, y);
      }
    });
  }
  
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function() {
    gotoHash($(this).attr('href'));
  });
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    gotoHash(location.hash);
  });

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

    // Navbar shrink function
    var navbarShrink = function () {
        const navbarCollapsible = document.body.querySelector('#mainNav');
        if (!navbarCollapsible) {
            return;
        }
        if (window.scrollY === 0) {
            navbarCollapsible.classList.remove('navbar-shrink')
        } else {
            navbarCollapsible.classList.add('navbar-shrink')
        }

    };

    // Shrink the navbar 
    navbarShrink();

    // Shrink the navbar when page is scrolled
    document.addEventListener('scroll', navbarShrink);



    // Collapse responsive navbar when toggler is visible
    const navbarToggler = document.body.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');
    const responsiveNavItems = [].slice.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('#navbarResponsive .nav-link')
    );
    responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
        responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(navbarToggler).display !== 'none') {
                navbarToggler.click();
            }
        });
    });

});
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.navbar-toggler')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse navbar-collapse");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }

function searchFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

var scrollOffset = 175;
$('a.nav-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(targetId);
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));

    if( $target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, $target.offset().top - scrollOffset);
    }
})
```

The CSS can't be uploaded because of the character limit, but the full code can be found here:
https://codepen.io/DeviceGucci/pen/bGWwVzd

NOTE: I am a beginner and the CSS code above is VERY bad because I've been copying and pasting different sections from a lot of templates, as well as modifying some of those sections.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Try this:

```
html {
  height: calc(100vh - 84px); /* Fix the height. The 84px here is the height of your nav. */
  margin-top: 84px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Don't scroll. */
}

body {
  height: 100%; /* Set the height to that of html. */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Draw a vertical scrollbar when needed. */
```

As far as I can tell, the only thing this breaks is your #page-top anchor, which isn't really strange since it's position is outside body. You can move that id to another element.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Another quick question, when I remove the "overflow: hidden" from the html, it stops working, is there a way to keep that?

Comment: This is one way of doing it. Another way is with margins/paddings on the sections. A third would be to use JavaScript to scroll to fixed points on the page. With this method, `html` doesn't scroll.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to upvote your answer but it doesn't let me because my account is new

Comment: It's fine. You're welcome. You could try accepting it if that works. :)