# using an anchor tag to link to an id , but with an offset

Tags: html, css

When using the anchor tag to go a specific id on my page, i encountered a problem, when i click the  link the text is hidden behind my Navbar.
I cant just add more padding or margin as it would destroy my design.
is there a way to implement some form of offset?

```
<a href="#text"></a>

<h1 id="text">Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the time and find the solution yourself. There are countless options from CSS to JS, but here are some that you can give a try.

Easiest solution:

```
#text {
   padding-top: 50px; /*height of your navbar*/
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Another solution, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323838/how-do-i-offset-the-navbar-anchors-so-that-the-content-is-not-hidden-by-the-navb), @LGT:

```
html {
  height: calc(100vh - 84px); /* Fix the height. The 84px here is the height of your nav. */
  margin-top: 84px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Don't scroll. */
}

body {
  height: 100%; /* Set the height to that of html. */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Draw a vertical scrollbar when needed. */
}
```

Another solution:

```
#text:target {
    padding-top: 50px; /*height of your navbar*/
} 
/*:taget pseudo class is used when user accesses the selected tag using href*/
```